# Is my search for this distribution correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $D_j \sim \rm{Ber}(q_j)$ for $j=1,2,\dots,n$ and let $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_n$ be constants. Find the $f_{D_j,C_j}$.

Answer (score 1):

First the only possible values for $x$ are $x=0,C_j$ $\forall
j=1,2...,n$$f_{Dj,Cj}=P(D_jC_j=0)=P(D_J=0)=q_j,P(D_jC_j=C_j)=P(D_J=1)=1-q_j$,$so$

$f_{Dj,Cj}$ $=${$q_j$ if $x=0$,$1-q_j$ if $x=C_j$,$0$ for $O.C$